# Unity not generating necessary C# scripts for Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I recently downloaded Unity to mess around with game development for a class. After making and trying to run a new hello world C# script, Visual Studio promptly spat out about 70 errors saying that various C# scripts were not found. All of the errors looked something like this:

```
"[File not found] : C:/Users/njenk/Documents/Unity Projects/New Unity Project/Packages/com.unity.textmeshpro/scripts/'c#FileThatINeed'"
```

I did some digging into my new project's files to see if VS was correct. There are five folders VS reported missing C# scripts from, all of which are in the Package directory. Here's a photo for reference:

[Package Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rw07f.png)

Every one of these folders was empty, not a single C# script to be found. VS is correct in saying it can't find anything. However, when I looked at my project in Unity's own file explorer, all of the 70 or so necessary C# scripts are present.

This seems very much like a case of VS not syncing correctly with Unity, but after several hours of looking online and messing around myself I came up empty handed. I found very few people with this type of error, so I am humbly request assistance from your end.

Comment: Make sure you have the proper Visual Studio Tools for Unity. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/cross-platform/getting-started-with-visual-studio-tools-for-unity?view=vs-2017

Comment: Usually you create a new project from Unity3d, set the preferences to use VisualStudio editor and then open the script in Unity3d which opens the project in VisualStudio. Like that all should be preconfigured to write code and even create new files from within VisualStudio. I did experience issues when trying to create a Unity3d-project from some IDE.

Comment: We frequently have Unity crap out on building the VS meta files.  As much as it pains me to say it, restarting Unity and then re-opening VS from within Unity usually fixes it (ie, "try turning it off and on again".).